# android apply function on editText

Tags: android

i have an EditText, and for every lettle the user type in this editText i want to apply a function on the whole text in EditText, that function is because i am writing in arabic and the arabic lettle appears not good ,but when i use `Farsi class` it becomes good, i will give you a simple example if the user wants to type 21, i want to apply function `output=3*editText.getText();`
so when he type 1 i will apply the function so the resutls that will appear on editText is:

```
output = 3*1 = 3
```

and when he type 2, i want to to display `12*3 = 36`

edit

```
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276): java.lang.StackOverflowError
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.text.DynamicLayout.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:261)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.text.DynamicLayout.<init>(DynamicLayout.java:150)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:4851)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:5348)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2688)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.localizedbasedcompetition.AnswerQuestion$3.onTextChanged(AnswerQuestion.java:149)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2691)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.localizedbasedcompetition.AnswerQuestion$3.onTextChanged(AnswerQuestion.java:149)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2691)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.localizedbasedcompetition.AnswerQuestion$3.onTextChanged(AnswerQuestion.java:149)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2691)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.localizedbasedcompetition.AnswerQuestion$3.onTextChanged(AnswerQuestion.java:149)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2691)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.localizedbasedcompetition.AnswerQuestion$3.onTextChanged(AnswerQuestion.java:149)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2691)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.localizedbasedcompetition.AnswerQuestion$3.onTextChanged(AnswerQuestion.java:149)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2691)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.localizedbasedcompetition.AnswerQuestion$3.onTextChanged(AnswerQuestion.java:149)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2691)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.localizedbasedcompetition.AnswerQuestion$3.onTextChanged(AnswerQuestion.java:149)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2691)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.localizedbasedcompetition.AnswerQuestion$3.onTextChanged(AnswerQuestion.java:149)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2691)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.localizedbasedcompetition.AnswerQuestion$3.onTextChanged(AnswerQuestion.java:149)
06-30 12:30:38.547: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChang
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fileNameEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
});
```

set a key listner for your view.

Comment: first thank you, second i am new to android , so plesae would you tell me more how to put that function on onKey?

Comment: code that you need to execute at every keypress. Just replace `//TODO Auto-generate method stub` comment with your code.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use [addTextChangedListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) and [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) like this:

```
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
textMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
textMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        //do your function here
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
});
```

Comment: hope i could accpet more than one answer :(

Comment: i got exception , when writing

Comment: `theAnswer.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   
   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
     theAnswer.setText("roma");
    
   }
   
   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
     int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
   }
   
   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
   }
  });`

Comment: Would you post it here, because I used this code exactly and it is working, maybe you are putting it in the wrong place.

Comment: you have to use this `theAnswer.setText("roma");` at `afterTextChanged()` not `onTextChanged()`

Comment: this is the code http://www.mediafire.com/?635euoc3upa61dh
and the excpetion on the edited question

Comment: even when i put it on `after` i got excpetion

Comment: maybe i undersnad why is gooing that, stack over flow , because when the text change , i change the textview so the textview always changed, right?

Comment: How you are declaring `theAnswer`, there must be an error above the code am showing you..

Comment: theAnswer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAnswerQuestoinAnswer);
   ((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
         .showSoftInput(theAnswer, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);

Comment: Try to show a Toast message at `afterTextChanged()` see if it works or not

Comment: see the answer i accept, his way works with me , really thank you very much

Comment: It is alright, glad you worked it out, FYI I was only insisting to work it out because it is the known and efficient way to do it. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        try
        {
         String s1 = editText.Text.ToString();
         byte[] b = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
         String s2 = new String(b, "UTF-8");
          editText.Text=(s2);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}
        } 
    });
```

Comment: have i to make any new change to the xml file? because i got exception

Comment: The exception was because you didn't enter numbers.

Comment: no no forget number, i just gave you example, the function is to convert the string to utf8 , not for numbers

Comment: someone say it is not ontextchange, said after textchange

Answer (score 1):

check this: [TextView.OnEditorActionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html)
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(yourListener)

edit: oh i was answering to fast. of course the answers telling use TextWatcher is the right way to go.